# UserLocation annotation custom title

Tags: iphone, ios, dictionary, mkmapview

i'm trying to set a custom title for the blue dot annotation (the user location annotation), i have tried this piece of code and it works in ViewforAnnotation delegate method:

((MKUserLocation *)annotation).title = @"custom title";

Someone knows if this is a private key? May my application will be rejected because i have tried to change user location annotation title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class for the default user location marker (at least in SDK 4.2) is MKUserLocationView, but this is not public so you cannot create an instance to modify without risking rejection from the app store. You'll have to create your own MKAnnotationView (or subclass of MKAnnotationView) instead.

But You can Use MKUserLocation see the following [Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKUserLocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html):
http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKUserLocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: `MKUserLocation` (which is what the OP is using) is public.  The class for its view is not public.  There should be no issue with the OP's code.

Comment: @Anna Sorry,My mistake i didn't noticed that you are right see the edited answer.